# Upgrade to 14.04 failed: segmentation fault on su

Tags: upgrade, skype, segmentation-fault

I just upgraded my 64 bit AMD desktop Xubuntu to 14.04 after easy, successful upgrades of 2 other machines to Lubuntu. There were numerous errors during the upgrade and now it seem to be in an almost unusable state. I cannot `su` without getting a segmentation fault and the Software Updater crashes. Skype doesn't work with Pulse Audio - no sound output.

I might add that there was a question about retaining the root privileges or replacing them during the installation. I tried to answer KEEP but was warned that this could cause problems so I answered REPLACE.

Also I saw something about encryption of the disk device and, if the key is different from the previous release this could cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the segfault problem as follows:

logged in as root using `ssh root@localhost`
ran `apt-get update`, which complained about duplicate sources:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
```

I then backed up `/etc/apt/sources.list` and commented out the lines for partner repositories.

I then ran

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt install -f
```

After that I could `su` and `sudo`.